# Сформировать массив B из отрицательных элементов массива A, имеющих четный индекс. Найти сумму квадратов элементов нового массива

Tags: c, массивы, циклы

Я не совсем понимаю как сформировать второй массив из первого

Вот условия задачи:
Дан массив A вещественного типа, содержащий n положительных и отрицательных элементов [-5, 5]. Сформировать массив B из отрицательных элементов массива A, имеющих четный индекс. Найти сумму квадратов элементов нового массива.

Вот что у меня получилось написать. Помогите дорешить, пожалуйста

В результате выполнения он выводит последнее, подходящее по условиям число, столько раз сколько встретились подходящие числа

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    
    int n,i=0,rand();
    
    printf("Введите_размер_массива: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    
    float a[n];
    
    printf("\nСгенерированный_массив: ");
    
    for (i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {   

        a[i]= -5 + rand()%10 * 1.153;
        printf("%.2f\t", a[i]);
    }
    
    int k=0;
    float b[k];
    
    for (i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {   
        if ((i%2==0)&&(a[i]<0))
        { 
            k++;
            b[k]=a[i];
            
        }
               
        
    }   

    printf("\nПолученныи_массив:      ");
    
    for (i=0; i<k; i++)
    {   

        printf("%.2f\t", b[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `int k=0; float b[k];` - это будет массив с нулевым размером, поменяйте на `n` : `int k=0; float b[n];` массив содержит элементы по индексам `0..n-1` у вас циклы неправильные `; i<=n;` поменяйте на `; i<n;`

Comment: Сначала подсчитайте количество отрицательных, а уже после этого заведите массив и заполните его (да, 2 прохода по `a[]`). `int k = 0; for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 2) if (a[i] < 0) k++; if (k) { float b[k]; ... } else puts("no matching items");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы сформировать из первого массива второй, нужно сначала пройтись по первому массиву и посчитать количество нужных нам элементов (в моём коде это делает ф-ция count). После этого мы создаем второй массив и начинаем его заполнять, вновь перебирая элементы первого массива и подбирая нужные нам (в моём коде это делается сразу после того, как выделяется память для массива b).

На основании предоставленного кода сделал этот. Ответ получается верный.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int count(float* a, int n) // считает количество нужных нам элементов
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 2)
    {
        if (a[i] < 0) count++;
    }
    return count;
}

main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    int n;

    printf("Введите размер массива: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);


    float* a = malloc(n * sizeof(float));
    printf("\nСгенерированный_массив: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        a[i] = -5 + rand() % 10 * 1.153;
        printf("%.2f\t", a[i]);
    }
    int i = 0;
    int k = count(a, n);
    float* b = malloc(sizeof(float) * k);
    for (int j = 0; j < k)
         if (a[j] < 0)
              b[i++] = a[j];

    printf("\nПолученныи_массив:      ");
    float sum = 0; // искомый ответ
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) // тут же можно подсчитать ответ.
    {
        printf("%.2f\t", b[i]);
        sum += b[i] * b[i];
    }
    printf("\nПолученный ответ: %.2f", sum);
}
```

Comment: можно уточнить у Вас, а в блок схеме как отобразить то, что до main() или тут их две будет на этот код?

Comment: Под "то, что до main()" подразумевается функция count()? Если да, то в ГОСТе 19.701-90 (гост по блок-схемам) есть пункт 3.2.2.1 предопределенный процесс - функция.
http://cert.obninsk.ru/gost/282/282.html

Comment: И, да. Насколько мне известно, предопределенные процессы нужно реализовывать, как отдельные схемы. Но примеров, к сожалению найти в интернете не могу...

Comment: то есть получается должно быть две сблок схемы?

Comment: 1) Зачем перебирать все индексы в `a[]` если интересуют значения только для **четных?** (достаточно идти *через один*) / 2) 2 вложенных цикла для заполнения `b[]` не нужны. Достаточно одного -- `int i = 0; for (int j = 0; j < n; j += 2) if (a[j] < 0) b[i++] = a[j];`

Comment: @kawagiri, Да. Должно быть две блок-схемы. Но можно в общем-то и в одну сделать. На этапе, когда в переменную k присваивается значение просто вставить цикл, который находится в функции count, но вместо прибавления значения к переменной count прибавлять значение к переменной k.

Comment: @avp, да. Так действительно будет правильнее, без лишних телодвижений, сам чего-то не додумался, что можно идти только по чётным индексам...

Comment: @markls, тогда поправьте текст ответа